# Error: React native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

just followed the instructions on facebook.github for create-react-native-app
first got: react-redux 5.0.6 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || react@^15.0.0-0 ....
then I uninstalled react-redux now getting this...

[here is package.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNXojt_xhBGYy1leUxnQ0lTWEE/view?usp=sharing)

ERROR STARTING PACKAGER

Error: React native is not installed. Please run npm install in your project directory.
1:23:51 AM: Error starting packager: Error: Couldn't start project. Please fix t
he errors and restart the project.
at E:\xdl\src\Project.js:1126:11
at next (native)
at step (E:\react-native\hello-world\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1504:
191)
at E:\react-native\hello-world\node_modules\xdl\build\Project.js:1504:361
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world@0.1.0 start: react-native-scripts start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-08
T20_23_51_654Z-debug.log

what could be my mistake or any suggestion about doing it right way ?

after npm install getting this

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit at E (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  expo/node-websql#18.0.0 resetting remote C:\Users\Jawad U
l Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-websql-
git-18-0-0-8213877d because of error: { Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\which\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) code: 'ENOGIT'
}
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\J
awad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-w
ebsql-git-18-0-0-8213877d: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Jawad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:expo/node-websql.git C:\Users\J
awad Ul Hassan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-expo-node-w
ebsql-git-18-0-0-8213877d: undefined
```

Comment: Try running `npm install`in your directory, if this doesn't solve, then edit your message adding your package.json file. Hope it helps

Comment: after npm install

Comment: Try to install git... And then redo your `npm install`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is might be because of npm version v5 so

npm 5 is still very buggy, please either use yarn or npm version 4.

```
npm i -g yarn
npm i -g npm@4
```

OR make sure you do npm install from your project directory. This is also one of the reason why you get this error

```
npm i
```

Answer (score 4):

When I Installed the react-navigation package that error occurred for me. I've fixed my issue

1. Delete node_modules, package-lock.json
2. run "`yarn install`".
3. run "`npm start`".

Answer (score 0):

You can see on the first line that git is not found

==> npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git

install git first.